# PowerShell Clear-ADAccountExpiration not performing in the same way as the manual method

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

I have issue when using PowerShell `Clear-ADAccountExpiration` to reset an account expiration date to `Never` in Active directory.

Here's an account that is going to expire:

```
get-ADUser osbor_ri -properties * | select AccountExpirationDate,accountExpires | fl

AccountExpirationDate : 31/12/2013 17:00:00
accountExpires        : 130330692000000000
```

As you can see it will expire on the `31/12/2013 17:00:00`. 
I want to clear this expiration and set it to `Never` expire; so I use the following `cmdlet`:

```
Clear-ADAccountExpiration osbor_ri
```

This clears the `AccountExpirationDate` varible in AD but doesn't clear `accountExpires` to 0 instead it's set to `9223372036854775807` each time.

```
get-ADUser osbor_ri -properties * | select AccountExpirationDate,accountExpires | fl

AccountExpirationDate : 
accountExpires        : 9223372036854775807
```

---

But when I use the manual method in AD to set an account to never expire the `accountExpires` varible is set to `0`.

[image]

```
get-ADUser osbor_ri -properties * | select AccountExpirationDate,accountExpires | fl

AccountExpirationDate : 
accountExpires        : 0
```

Why does the Powershell `Clear-ADAccountExpiration` not clear down `accountExpires` varible to `0` in the same way that the manual method does when setting an account to never expire?

Also does leaving the `accountExpires = 9223372036854775807` mean the account will still expire as some point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The date when the account expires. This value represents the number of
>   100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC). A value of 0 or
>   0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (9223372036854775807) indicates that the account
>   never expires.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675098(v=vs.85).aspx